# Cannot reference a field before it is * defined" error

Tags: java, reference

```
public class Test1 {
 static{
    a=20;  
 //  System.out.println(a); //Line 4
    }
    static int a=getA();

private static int getA() {
    return 10;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(a);
}
}
```

Why it showing error ?but if remove the Line working fine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you declare `a` before the static initializer:

```
public class Test1 {
    static int a=getA();
    static{
        a=20;  
        System.out.println(a);
    }

    private static int getA() {
        return 10;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Static initialization is done in the order it's written in the code. That means that in your code, you first set `a` to `20` and then initialize it to `getA()` - which is just as illegal as if you would have done it inside a function.

Answer (score 3):

**Order matters.**

`static` fields, block  executes based on the **order** they placed in source code.

Move the declaration up . So that It can available to below blocks.