# How do I have two classes in different lines interact with each other in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, class

I'm new to Java, and I'm making a text-based adventure game. In my game, there are multiple rooms, and the rooms each hold an array of items. I have a class called "door," and I want room A to have a door leading to room B and vice versa. But when I do this:

```
    public room A = new room(new items[] {
new door(B)});
    public room B = new room(new items[] {
new door(A)});
```

I get the **error** message `"Cannot reference a field before it is defined"` (I'm using Eclipse).

Is there a way to make this work?

I know that that means it can't tell a class to do something before that class is defined, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Classes aren't "defined" in a sequence - you can access any class anywhere. Also, classes don't do things - objects do. Also, the error message says field, not class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot reference a field before it is \* defined" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22198527/cannot-reference-a-field-before-it-is-defined-error)

Comment: If you need two objects to refer to each other you can't do it in their constructors.  You need to create the objects, *then* tell them about each other.  The way you're trying to do it, one of them will always not be created yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to add the items after you create the rooms. This means you'll need to write an `addItem` method in `room`.

```
public room A = new room();
public room B = new room();

{ // this is the start of an "instance initializer"; it runs before any constructors (but after field initializers)
    // if you have a constructor, you could choose to put this in the constructor instead; personal preference
    A.addItem(new door(B));
    B.addItem(new door(A));
}
```

Comment: @BobMonkeywarts: I'm glad that this answer helped you (1+). As an aside, you will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Also you should avoid using trivial variable names such as `b` or `s` unless they are being used for trivial purposes such as the index of a for loop. Instead use names that have some meaning so that your code becomes self-commenting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the items of A after both A and B have been initialized. For instance:

```
public room A = new room();
public room B = new room();
{
    B.setItems(new items[] {A});
    A.setItems(new items[] {B});
}
```